# MOV parameters understanding and capacitance

Tags: calculation, mov

I want to add a MOV to the input of my circuit. I came across the following [MOV](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/MOV07D.pdf).

The specs I require will be the following:

1. Max voltage 300V AC rms
2. Surge voltage 1.4kV
3. Response time 8/20us

I have seen some ciruits like the below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft1hix.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My questions:

1. What does 8/20us mean?
2. What is the purpose of R1 and how should I calculate its resistance?
3. MOV has a capacitance value at 1kHz, what does this mean? What will the capacitance be below 1kHz and above kHz? How does it affect a ciruit?

Answer (score 0):

1. Rise and fall time of the specified voltage pulse. 8 us rise time and 20 us fall time.
2. Limit the current and voltage. The higher resistance your circuit can cope with during normal operation the less current the MOV needs to sink for a given max allowed voltage. To calculate the resistance, take your lowest input voltage and worst case max load. How much voltage drop and dissipation can you allow here. That sets the upper bound for R1. Your inrush current could very well be the limiting factor as well for the peak power rating of the resistor. Assume max allowed input voltage. Please note, if you already are meeting the requirements with a MOV you can afford, don’t go any higher in R1 value.
3. They need to test it at some frequency and the manufacturer chose 1 kHz. Assume flat frequency response and simulate with that value. Ok? Proceed to real testing.

Comment: Gosh darn it. How do I uncheck community Wiki?

Comment: for number 2, how would I calculate the resistor value?

Comment: @JoeyB Updated.

Comment: I'm still confused. In my mind, in order to calculate R, I would take the highest input voltage minus the clamping voltage and then divide it by the max current (at the rated clamping voltage). Would that not work?

Comment: @JoeyB Because at minimum input voltage, current is higher. Perhaps you are confused normal operation (what I’m trying to convey) with clamping? If you select an R just to satisfy the MOV, it may drop so much voltage your product won’t run anymore.

Comment: So if my minimum source input voltage is 5V, how would I then calculate the value for R?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. By load impedance is very high, it only draws around 10nA.